# Access VBA to Set Field Location

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am wanting to use the `Alter Table` statement to add a few fields to a table.  I want to control the location of the fields when they are added.  I tried the below syntax, and it will add the field, but it is not added to position 2 it is added to the last position in the table.

How should this be altered in order to control the position of the field being added?

```
Set td = db.TableDefs("InformationSeminar")
With td
    .Fields.Append .CreateField("FirstName", dbText, 50)
    .Fields![FirstName].OrdinalPosition = 2
    .Fields.Refresh
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding a column in a specific position, you will need to move up all other columns with an equal or higher position one place too, to free up the position you're inserting it into

```vb
Set td = db.TableDefs("InformationSeminar")
Dim fld As Field
For Each fld In td.Fields
   With fld
        If .OrdinalPosition >= 2 Then
            .OrdinalPosition = .OrdinalPosition + 1
        End If
    End With
Next fld
With td
    .Fields.Append .CreateField("FirstName", dbText, 50)
    .Fields![FirstName].OrdinalPosition = 2
    .Fields.Refresh
End With
```